# find command to delete all files with specific last modified date

Tags: shell, find

```
touch -m -d @$(( $(stat -c %Y file.txt) - 7200 )) file.txt
```

[This command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41342/how-do-i-mass-convert-the-last-modified-dates-in-a-particular-directory) sets the last modified date on a single file. How could I edit it to use `find` to set a predefined last modified date, e.g. Dec 25, 2020, on all files in a folder and its subfolders?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the linked answer? "If you put this into a shell script, you can call it from `find` or `xargs` letting you use find to select the files you want to change."

Answer (score 2):

The command in the question makes a relative adjustment, subtracting two hours from the file's timestamp. If you're satisfied with a fixed timestamp then use:

```
find . -exec touch -t 201303101513 {} +
```

Comment: Thanks John. Thant's perfect! Quick Q. I am using `find dir1 -newermt 'Feb 12 2021' \! -newermt 'Feb 12 2021' -delete` to try and delete all files (files only and not folders) with a Last Modified date on Feb 12 2021. The command will delete the files and empty folders with that Last Modified Date however it won't delete folder with files in them. The error states eg `find: cannot delete ‘dir1/test’: Directory not empty` ...how to I amend that command to just delete the appropriate files and ignore folder deletion? Can I use `-type f` someplace?

Comment: So `find -type f dir1 -newermt 'Feb 25 2022' \! -newermt 'Feb 26 2022' -delete` produces the error: "
find: paths must precede expression: dir1
" ...where should I place -type f?

Comment: Ok this works: `find dir1 -newermt 'Feb 25 2022' -type f \! -newermt 'Feb 26 2022' -delete`

Answer (score 0):

This changes the Last Modified Date in folders and subfolders:

```
find -print | while read filename; do
    touch -t 201303101513 "$filename"
done
```

... I hope it helps others